# create CSV file in c#net Window application

Tags: c#

create CSV file in c#net Window application at button click event

Comment: Show us what you've tried and say what didn't work.

Comment: What is the source of your data? Is it dataset? or form controls? or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use simple string or stringbuilder to construct CSV File.
I can give pseudocode :

```
string csvString = "";
for each column in row
    csvString += column.value + ","

writeToFile(csvString,filePath);
```